# Which is the best way to mask / hide tomcat version from error pages?

Tags: tomcat, version

Could somebody please let me know which of the following two approaches is recommended and why :

- Make the necessary changes to
  ServerInfo.properties
- Define "error-page" in web.xml

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520162/reducing-information-disclosure-in-tomcat-error-pages?rq=1

Answer (score 33):

The answers are a bit outdated, so: If you're using a tomcat 6 or newer (I've tested on tomcat 7) you can use the `ErrorReportValve` to achieve the same in a way that is much easier to configure and maintain. Just add the following lines to the `Host` section of your `server.xml` (where you should already have the `AccessLogValve`:

```xml
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve"
       showReport="false" 
       showServerInfo="false"/>
```

In this way you are hiding the server info and (because of the optional `showReport="false"`) also the stack traces.

You can read more about this in the [Security How To](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html) and in the documentation of the [Error Report Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Error_Report_Valve).

Answer (score 5):

I'd make the changes to ServerInfo.properties regardless - there may be other places to get the ServerInfo.properties version information than only error pages.  (Maybe someone leaves up the default home page, samples, etc. and these may have it.)

Define error pages in your web app if you want - a quicker option may be to globally change your default error pages by specifying it in CATALINA_HOME/conf/web.xml - this will use your new specified error pages by default even if a developer forgets to specify error pages for their app.

Answer (score 5):

Changing `ServerInfo.properties` is the most secure. If you for example have deployed a webapp on `http://example.com/contextname`, one could still get a `404` by `http://example.com/blah` or so. One could also get it programmatically by using a robot to Send a request with an unsupported method (which returns `503` error page).

That said, I honestly don't see any valid reasons to hide Tomcat version from it. This information actually adds no value for "normal users". It also doesn't stop any hacker from trying everything to get it down or exploit security holes (if there were any...). They don't worry about whether the version is displayed or not. For the "normal users" I would still use a custom error page which is a bit more integrated in the style of the webapp in question so that it is less "scary" and thus improves user experience.

Comment: It's amazing how things change...

https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-887/version_id-29850/Apache-Tomcat-5.5.20.html

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't override the default `server.xml` nor `content.xml`. So I added the following lines to my source

```java
Context ctx = tomcat.addWebapp("", root-Path());
if (Paths.get("context.xml").toFile().exists()) {
    ctx.setConfigFile(Paths.get("context.xml").toUri().toURL());
}
```

and created a new `context.xml` in the root folder to override the default context.xml.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve" 
           showReport="false"
           showServerInfo="false" />
</Context>
```

Reference: [GitHub](https://github.com/secure-device-onboard/pri-fidoiot/blob/1.1-rel/protocol/src/main/java/org/fidoalliance/fdo/protocol/StandardHttpServer.java#L221)